# QFontDialog: get font color

Tags: qt, fonts

On mac, the `QFontDialog` is mapped to a nice system font dialog.
It is possible to choose between every system fonts and it is also possible to choose the font colour and effects (underline, strikethrough etc...)

How can I get those attributes?

```
bool ok;
QFont font = QFontDialog::getFont(&ok, QFont("Helvetica", 10), this);
if (ok) {
    // do something
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [Qt's docs](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qfontdialog.html) it does not seem to be possible to get color property when using `QFontDialog`.

When using Mac you get the Mac native panel which also displays the color. It is recommended not to use the native panel on Mac:

> Use Qt's standard font dialog on the Mac instead of Apple's native font panel. (Currently, the native dialog is never used, but this is likely to change in future Qt releases.)

Note, the above part (that it is likely to change in future release) was present since version qt4 on the docs...

You can use `option` property to use Qt's dialog:  `fontDialog->setOption(QFontDialog::DontUseNativeDialog);`

For the underline, strikethrough and other font-related properties, you can access them through [`QFont`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qfont.html) API, e.g., `QFont::underline()`.